# Add a common property to all sub-features of a feature collection in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, zonal-statistics

I am new to earth engine and am struggling with a very simple task. I want to calculate the average NDVI for the counties of Maine for the month of January 2018. I manage to do so but, before exporting it to .csv, I wanted to add a property to each of the sub-features (counties) with the date ('2018-01-01') of the NDVI.

I try it with the `.set()` and `setMulti` functions but do not manage to achieve what I want. In particular, these functions add a property to the "overall" feature collection, and not to each sub-feature of the former. When I do that and export it as a .csv, the information is lost.

In short: I would like to add a property `{date: '2018-01-01'}` to each of the sub-features. Namely that the property in figure 1 is actually inside the properties in figure 2. I am attaching the code after the images.

**Figure 1:**

[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2:**

[image: Figure 2]

**Code:**

```js
// Load a collection of US counties with census data properties.
var maine = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1S4EB6319wWW2sWQDPhDvmSBIVrD3iEmCLYB7nMM');

// let us use only counties from Maine:
maine = maine.filter(ee.Filter.eq('StateName', 'Maine'));

// loading recent NDVI data:
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31'));
var ndvi = dataset.select('NDVI');
ndvi = ndvi.mean();  // monthly mean -- need to average out as there are 2 images in this time period

// clipping into my AOI:
var ndvi_maine = ndvi.clip(maine);

// Average NDVI per county:
var means = ndvi_maine.reduceRegions({
  collection: maine,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
});

// selecting only desired columns and transforming it into a feature object:
means = ee.Feature(means.select(['CntyFips', 'mean']));

means = means.setMulti({date: '2018-01-01'});   // trying to add properties

print(means);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `map` a function over the collection:

```js
// Load a collection of US counties with census data properties.
var maine = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1S4EB6319wWW2sWQDPhDvmSBIVrD3iEmCLYB7nMM');

// let us use only counties from Maine:
maine = maine.filter(ee.Filter.eq('StateName', 'Maine'));

// loading recent NDVI data:
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31'));
var ndvi = dataset.select('NDVI');
ndvi = ndvi.mean();  // monthly mean -- need to average out as there are 2 images in this time period

// clipping into my AOI:
var ndvi_maine = ndvi.clip(maine);

// Average NDVI per county:
var means = ndvi_maine.reduceRegions({
  collection: maine,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
});

means = means.map(function(ft){
  return ee.Feature(ft).set('date', '2018-01-01')
})

print(means)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/b5a3f45d65c6f102960be2dc2252c0bd